# What are good options to create a simple standalone desktop GUI (requirements included!)

Tags: user-interface, desktop

Here are my requirements for a very very simple desktop gui I need to make.

Totally standalone -  Needs to be double clickable with out the reliance on having anything installed on the users machine.

Simple GUI -  Bare bones.  Will be loading a list from a file that will be stored in a dropdown or w/e.

Rock solid on Windows distributions -  XP, Vista etc

Bonus (Not strong requirement) - Could create a mac app from the same source

Background:

I am a java developer and have created a demo program that runs off a flash drive.  You just pop it in and double click.  It loads a GUI which reads a file and lets you select contents of that file for a drop down enter some other info and hit save and saves a new file with the details.

I am potentially limited by space so I don't think I have room to bundle a jre with the app.  We do not want to require the users to have a JRE installed so it can be as dumbed down as possible.

So I am looking for alternatives and have little experience in standalone desktop apps so seek some advice.

I am not opposed to using something that will only work on Windows if it is that much stronger as we can create a separate program for Mac since they should all have a JRE installed.

So far I've been looking into python with py2exe, C++, C#.  I don't really know the pro's and con's and would love some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Delphi is very comfortable for these tasks. Easy Gui building, single exe with copy&go installations, Object pascal as language,...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi

Comment: Seems perfect Except it looks like the license for this is 999.  At this point this little task does not justify us spending that much on it.  Thanks though!

Comment: There are free versions that should suffice for small tasks!